# JMeter distributed testing does not return results

Tags: jmeter

I have connect my PC as master to other PCs and I run the distributed test but all I get is an empty jtl file with only the headers of a table..

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know.

From your beautiful screenshot we can only see that 0 samplers were executed which perfectly explains empty results.

Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for jmeter master and slave, most probably you will find the reason there.

The most common reasons are:

1. Incorrect [RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) so there is no bi-directional communication between the master and slaves
2. Your test relies on external data, i.e. uses [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and you forgot to copy the CSV file(s) to slave machine(s)
3. Your test relies on [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and you forgot to install JMeter Plugins on the slave machine(s), you can install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) and open the .jmx test plan on the slave - the plugins manager should detect and install at least the majority of the plugins used in the script

Comment: I dont use plug in. The jmeter.log has no information for errors. I am checking RMI configuration again... By the way I use custom csv files for my tests on the desktop. Where do I have to copy them on the other machines?

Comment: If you use full path - create the same folder structure on the slave(s), if you use relative path - copy the CSV files to the location relative to JMeter bin folder

Comment: I confirm. The problem was the path of the csv files at the slave(s) machine(s). Closed